# Polly Fallback policy causes "ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream" the 2nd time fallback is activated on ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, polly

I'm writing a REST API that calls another REST API using Polly resiliency policies.
I got the Fallback policy to work fine the first time but the 2nd time it's triggered throws an error:

```
System.IO.StreamHelpers.ValidateCopyToArgs(Stream source, Stream destination, int bufferSize)
System.IO.MemoryStream.CopyToAsync(Stream destination, int bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.IO.Stream.CopyToAsync(Stream destination)
ProxyBase.HttpResponseMessageResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context) in HttpResponseMessageResult.cs
+                await stream.CopyToAsync(context.HttpContext.Response.Body);
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
```

The HttpResponseMessageResult class is a custom converter from the HttpResponseMessage returned by the client in the fallback handler to the IActionResult expected by the controller method. Here is the code of the method where the exception is thrown:

```
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)_responseMessage.StatusCode;

        using (var stream = await _responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(context.HttpContext.Response.Body);
            await context.HttpContext.Response.Body.FlushAsync();
        }
```

And here is my policy:

```
                var fallbackPolicy = Policy<HttpResponseMessage>.Handle<Exception>()
                .OrResult(r => r.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout)
                .FallbackAsync(
                    GetFailoverResponse(fallbackUrl),
                    (ct,cx) => {
                            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                              return client.GetAsync(fallbackUrl + ct.Result.RequestMessage.RequestUri.AbsolutePath);
                        });
                clientBuilder.AddPolicyHandler(fallbackPolicy);
```

I double-checked that the returned HttpResponseMessage is fresh the 2nd time - it is unique, I can see that the queryString is different when I add a random parameter.

I also tried replacing the actual failing call directly with the fallback call (i.e. to get Polly out of the equation) - like this it works fine, so it is polly delivering the HttpResponseMessage with a closed stream for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to have been related to (ab)use of the 2nd parameter of the FallbackAsync method: it's meant to run before returning the fallback result but not for generating the result itself, which is what I was doing in the broken version of the code above.

The method has various overloads but they mostly support two parameters and vary in the exact datatypes: fallbackResult and onFallbackAsync. In the broken example I was returning a static fallbackResult as a backup, even though my onFallbackAsync delegate returns Task. My (faulty) understanding was that this would be the HTTP response that will be returned by the policy. Apparently, under the hood it was actually returning the static response, which had its stream already read by the 2nd time it was used.

The solution is to use another overload of the first parameter, one that will not return a static HttpResponseMessage but will pass the HTTP request context to a lambda which can execute the fallback HTTP request, like this:

```
    var fallbackPolicy = Policy<HttpResponseMessage>.Handle<Exception>()
    .OrResult(r => r.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout)
    .FallbackAsync(
        (res, cx, ct) => {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            return client.GetAsync(fallbackUrl + res.Result.RequestMessage.RequestUri.AbsolutePath);
        },
        (ct, cx) =>
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });
```